# rename multiple pdf files thru CMD

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, batch-rename

Have 2500 pdf files in a folder with fixed length name with a delimiter " _ "
200422028240000148_8393929.pdf
742022028240000014_4366273.pdf

Need to rename with first name available before the delimiter
200422028240000148.pdf
742022028240000014.pdf

How can i do with CMD as well powershell without currupting file and also cant use external utility or tool this being production server

Comment: [1] use `Get-ChildItem` to get the files. [2] use the `.BaseName` property of each file object to get the name of the file without the extension. [3] use `.Split()` to split on the underscore. [4] use the index of the part you want - the beginning would be $SplitResult[0]`. [5] reassemble the file name. [6] use that to rename the file. [7] make _extensive_ use of the help system via `Get-Help ThingYouWantHelpWIth`.

Comment: As simple as `for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=_." %%a in ('dir /B *.pdf') do ren %%a_%%b.%%c %%a.%%c` (in a Batch file)

Answer (score 0):

This is really basic PowerShell.

Please, take some time to lookup the workings of [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7) and [Rename-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7) to figure out how below code works:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\TheFolder' -Filter '*.pdf' -File | Rename-Item -NewName {
    ($_.BaseName -split '_')[0] + $_.Extension
}
```

Comment: I would suggest, for safety, using `-LiteralPath`, instead of `-Path`, and that you modify the `-Filter` to `'??????????????????_???????.pdf'`. Then you make it clear that the code above requires a minimum install of PowerShell v3.0, or offer a version without `-File`, instead using `Where-Object`. Then you could whilst you're at it, guarantee your file names are matching those required by using something like `-Not $_.PSIsContainer -And $_.BaseName -Match '^\d{18}_\d{7}'`. I also have a niggling feeling that using `.SubString(0,18)` may be quicker than using `-Split`.

Comment: @Compo Good suggestions, but that is why I added links to the `Get-ChildItem` and `Rename-Item` cmdlets to have the OP read, learn and try out for himself. The question now is without any effort at all and also does not state what PowerShell version to use.

Comment: @Compo - These are all good suggestions if it is guaranteed that the file names will have exactly eighteen (18) characters before the LOW LINE. If it is, fine. I have seldom found environments where such an assumption always holds true. The OP should, at a minimum, get onto the current Microsoft PowerShell 5.x release.

Comment: I understand that, but I often find it confusing that Microsoft defaults to providing the v7 pages, and makes it difficult for you to see which commands or options you can use in which versions. Let's say, I was using Windows 7, and haven't manually searched, found and downloaded PS 3+, and wanted to introduce the [Where-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7), command in my previous comment. It appears to incorrectly suggest there that I need v3.0 to use `-Match`, but you can inside _scriptblock_ braces. It's a mess.

Comment: TBF @lit, I was assuming, that "fixed length name with a delimiter `_`", meant that the delimiter was always in the same character position in each. I also assumed that all characters other than the delimiter were digits too, and neither of those things were guaranteed by the OP. However, given the supplied criteria, _as opposed to the assumed_, validation should require that we, at the very least, check for a twenty six character basename. I suppose checking for at least one delimiter would be advisable, _but you could technically pass everything without delimiters, any without wont split_.

Comment: @Compo - If you are on Windows 7, we should ask you to come back when you are on a supported platform. There are nostalgia places to ask questions about old systems.

Comment: @lit, I'm not on any version of Windows, I don't have a PC at all! The point is that the OP did not provide sufficient information to identify which versions of powershell were available to them, so a minimum version should be mentioned. BTW, Windows 7 currently retains around 25-30% of Windows market share presently, so its users should not just be discounted as not worthy of helping. Remember that the issue is not with the version of Windows, but with the version of Powershell. Microsoft hasn't added it as an updateable component in the built-in update facility, so it cannot be assumed, too.